# Jasmine - Unble to get DOM elements

Tags: unit-testing, jasmine, angular-directive

I am testing an angularjs directive that manipulates the DOM.

I am trying to get the element in my Jasmine spec, so that I can test the functionality of the directive. However, when I use `document.getElementsByClassName` or `TagName` or `ID`, it doesn't return anything. Does anyone have ideas about this?

```
html = document.getElementsByClassName('analog');
console.dir(html);
```

Comment: Probably the elements you're trying to query aren't attached to the document. Maybe Angulars test tooling does not add the element to the document? Please create a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so that others can reproduce your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you create a test in headless browser/chrome etc., you could append a dummy object, for example JQuery node, then remove that node in afterEach.

E.g.

```
beforeEach(() => {
    var mockHtml = $('<div class="form-group" style="position: absolute;left: -10000px;"><input class="testInput" id="some_input"></div>');
    $('body').append(mockHtml);
});

afterEach(() => {
    $('.form-group').remove();
});
```