# jasmine test for jquery element

Tags: jquery, karma-jasmine

I have a function need to write unit test:

```
  public refresh(): void {
    this.closeAllPopups().subscribe(() => {
      const refreshButton = $('.refresh').last();
      if (refreshButton.length) {
        refreshButton[0].click();
      }
    });
  }
```

I wonder how I can set $('.refresh').last().length not 0.

My unit test 1 as below:

```
  it('should click refresh button element', fakeAsync(() => {
    spyOnProperty($('.refresh').last(), 'length').and.returnValue(1);
    console.log($('.refresh').last());
    spyOn(actions, 'closeAllPopups').and.returnValue(Observable.of(true));
    spyOn($.fn, 'click');
    actions.refresh();
    tick();
    expect($.fn.click).toHaveBeenCalled();
  }));
```

My unit test 2 as below:

```
  it('should click refresh button element', fakeAsync(() => {
    const button = document.createElement('div');
    button.setAttribute('class', 'refresh');
    console.log($('.refresh').last());
    spyOn(actions, 'closeAllPopups').and.returnValue(Observable.of(true));
    spyOn($.fn, 'click');
    actions.refresh();
    tick();
    expect($.fn.click).toHaveBeenCalled();
  }));
```

all the unit test `console.log($('.refresh').last())` display n.fn.init.length = 0. How can I change it?

Comment: Is it a headless chrome test? If so, you would have to mock the element. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37011652/jasmine-unble-to-get-dom-elements)

Comment: Thanks, it really help with me.